# Matlab coder fzero function

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function, matlab-coder

I am trying to convert a MATLAB code to C code using "MATLAB Coder", but anonymous functions are not allowed.

How can I convert for example an `fzero` function as

```
myfun = @(x,c) cos(c*x);  % parameterized function
c = 2;                    % parameter
fun = @(x) myfun(x,c);    % function of x alone
x = fzero(fun,0.1)
```

into a normal function, for instance, to convert the whole code to C.

Comment: What is an "undefined function" in this context? I don't see anything undefined.

Comment: sorry, I will rename it. You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "anonymous" functions, not "undefined" functions, just to clear up the terminology.

To convert the following to a named function:

```
myfun = @(x,c) cos(c*x);  % parameterized function
```

write this:

```
function result = myfun(x,c)

result = cos(c*x);

end
```

For the second function, write this:

```
function result = myfun2(x)
c = 2;
result = cos(c*x);

end
```

Finally, call fzero like this:

```
x = fzero(@myfun2, 0.1);
```

Comment: what should I do if $c$ is also a parameter (not a constant = 2)?

Comment: Not sure if I follow...in the first function, `c` is a parameter, along with x.  In your example, you made c constant so you could pass a 1-argument function to fzero.  You could also make `x` constant, and pass a function of `c` only.